# Facebook connect full screen login

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook, sharekit

Using FBConnect with ShareKit, how can I make the login window be full screen and not a popup style view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at `FBLoginDialog` and override `show` to size the view/frame to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

In FBDialog.m change the scale value from 0.6 to 1.0 like this:

`if (FBIsDeviceIPad()) {
    // On the iPad the dialog's dimensions should only be 60% of the screen's
    scale_factor = 1.0f;
  }`